# Is it possible to use aiogram to send messages without handlers?

Tags: python, aiogram

Recently I've been writing bot which parses site and sends message to users, whenever new information appears. Is it possible to make it on aiogram? Thank you for your answer in advance

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. it is.
But you have to store user_id of your users, then when "information appears" you take from your storage user_ids and send message to each user. Also it is unreal to send message for all users in one time due to telegram limits ([see here](https://core.telegram.org/bots/faq#my-bot-is-hitting-limits-how-do-i-avoid-this)).